# Docker compose throwing find: ‘’: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I am trying to execute docker-compose on top of `official Cassandra docker image`.

Basically, I am trying to set a few of properties present inside Cassandra image at `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` .
My docker-compose looks like

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  cassandra:
      image: cassandra:3.11.6
      ports:
        - "9042:9042"
      environment:
        - CASSANDRA_ENABLE_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTIONS=true
      # restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./cassandra-dc-1:/usr/local/bin/
      container_name: cassandra-dc-1
      entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
      # command: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` I get below error, from the directory where I have the `docker-compose.yaml` present

```
cassandra-dc-1 | find: ‘’: No such file or directory
cassandra-dc-1 exited with code 1
```

I tried giving

1. Absolute path in the **volume**
2. ./cassandra-dc-1:/usr/local/bin/ -- using this with file 'docker-entrypoint.sh' which I want to copy within docker

I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I am trying to set a few of properties present inside
> Cassandra image at `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` .

If you just to set properties in `yaml` file you do not need to override the entrypoint as it will hide a lot of executable not only entrypoint by doing below

```
      volumes:
        - ./cassandra-dc-1:/usr/local/bin/
```

**Do not mound the whole directory `/usr/local/bin/`.**

If you just want to override entrypoint then do the following

```
      volumes:
        - ./cassandra-dc-1/docker-entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**Custom config file**

```
FROM cassandra:3.11.6
copy my_customconfig.yml /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

That's all you need to run with custom config, copy the config during build time.

or with docker-compose

```
      volumes:
        - ./cassandra.yaml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

[Configuring Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)

Comment: Thanks @Adiii , I was unnecessary making it complicated. I went ahead with replacing the cassandra.yaml